# How to set ssh server's date time automatically using MobaXTerm at each connection?

Tags: mobaxterm

We have an embedded linux boad and connecting it over ssh by using MobaXTerm v23.5 from my Windows 11 PC.

I want to set the linux board's date time automatically each time when I connect it with MobaXTerm.

I can do it with following terminal command in WSL, Linux but I couldn't do the same thing using MobaXTerm. Any idea how to do that with it?

```
ssh root@192.168.42.1 date -s @$(date -u +"%s")
```